# Repurchasing auto renewable subscription iOS

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am working on auto renewable subscription. I have following issue on sandbox test environment also when testing on products.storekit test file:

When user is already subscribed and tries to subscribe again he gets alert
"You're currently subscribed to this." with "manage" and "ok" options. After tapping OK observer function `func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])` is called with new transaction with new date and status *.purchased*. Is it correct behaviour of store kit? If yes how can I determine if the transaction is real purchase or failed attempt to re-purchase?

Code for purchasing subscription:

```
let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
```

XCode 13.4, iOS 15.6.1

Comment: First, it may simply be a renewal transaction that is being posted; subscriptions renew at an accelerated rate in the sandbox to help with testing.  Second, it doesn't matter why you got the transaction. You just process it and update the current subscription expiration date based on the transaction.

Comment: It is not renewal transaction, I have set accelerated rate to 1/2 hour, it simply creates transaction when I press OK button on alert. And I cannot use transaction date because it generates actual date in the transaction, not original purchase date.

Comment: For a subscription transaction, it is the expiration date that is important. It is correct that a new transaction is delivered when the user taps "ok".  Consider: a user runs your app on a new device. Your app does not realise that they have an existing subscription so they do not get the subscription benefit. They attempt to purchase, get the dialog, click "ok" and your transaction observer receives a purchase transaction. Your app processes this and the user starts to receive the subscription benefit. It is similar to a user attempting to purchase a previously purchased non-consumable iap

Comment: It isn't a "failed attempt to re-purchase". It is a successful attempt to re-purchase.

Comment: ok, but transaction object does not contain expiration date. Where can I find it?

Comment: It is in [the receipt](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html) - you need to process the receipt for subscription purchases. You can't simply calculate forward from the transaction date.  Depending on the minimum ios version you support you can also look at storekit2